# How can I make sifr3 fonts from .otf fonts?

Tags: sifr

I need to make sifr3 fonts from .otf fonts, how can I do that?

Comment: Unless its done with METAFONT (or, I suppose, PostSript type 3), creating fonts doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: Could be so, but sifr site says that people should ask their questions at stackoverflow

Comment: the question is. why would you ever want flash font on the web year 2016?

Comment: @Endless Question was asked 6 years ago when flash fonts were still used on web sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Flash (the format ist available on the sifr site) or this: [directly on the sifr site](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/without-flash-pro)

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://onlinefontconverter.com to convert your fonts to TTF and then what @Polygraf suggested.